# How to run the if loop in the given code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code works from `count=0` to count=9. Then it does not get in to the other elif code. I have commented which part is not working below. I have tried so many time by checking the value of count, still I could not find why the code doesn't work

```
count =0
for line in sys.stdin:
  line = line.strip()
  print(count)
  if (count==0):
    a = int(line)                   #no of series
    count=1


  elif(count==1):             #2nd line 2 players 3 mtches
    plyrs_mtchs=[]  
    plyrs_mtchs= line.split()
    print(plyrs_mtchs)
    count+=1                        # #no of players , no of matches

  elif(count==2 or count==6):              
    players.append(str(line))
    print(players)
    count+=1


  elif(count==3,5 or count==7,9):               
    currenplyr = players[len(players)-1]        
    predict.append(line.split())
    count+=1


  elif(count==10 or count==11): #this code doesn't work      
    actual.append(line.split())
    count+=1

  elif(count==12):              #this code doesnt work
    actual.append(line.split())
    count+=1
```

Comment: `elif(count==3,5 or count==7,9)` won't work either.

Comment: It works well no problem with it

Comment: On the contrary, that is *exactly* your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression:

```
elif(count==3,5 or count==7,9):
```

does not do what you think it does. You are not testing if `count` has one of 4 possible values there. Python sees this as 3 different expressions forming a tuple:

```
count==3
5 or count==7
9
```

producing the output

```
(False, 5, 9)
```

if `count` is not equal to 3 and

```
(True, 5, 9)
```

if it is. `5 or <some other expression` will always return `5` because it is a non-zero numeric value, so true, and it doesn't matter what the other side of the `or` operator evaluates as anymore.

A tuple with 3 elements is *always true* in a boolean context, because it is a non-empty container. As such, that `elif` branch is **always** going to match if preceding `if` or `elif` tests failed.

See the [*Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) and [*Boolean Operations*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) sections for details on how boolean testing and `or` work.

Use the [`in` operator membership test](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) instead:

```
elif count in {3, 5, 7, 9}:
```

where the test will be true if `count` has a value that's in the set of 4 possible values.

Comment: @Pieters: Very nice and detailed answer. Just curious why you prefer a set in `count in {1, 2}` over a much simpler constant object - a tuple - like `count in (1, 2)`? Has the set an advantage? Thanks.

Comment: @VPfB yes, set membership tests are faster (O(1) constant time). The Python 3 compiler actually stores a `frozenset()` object with the bytecode as it cannot be mutated anyway.

Comment: @Pieters: Just tried a quick timing test and the set is faster indeed. Did not expect that for a really small set, because a hash must be computed. Learned something new again. Thanks.

Comment: finally I found what it really was. Thanks for the explanation.